# Can I run the Linux Fortran compiler for Intel with Cygwin?

Tags: windows-7, linux, cygwin, compile

I'm on Windows 7, 64-bit. Can I run the Linux Fortran compiler for Intel with Cygwin?

Answer (score 2):

While Cygwin provides a [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)-compatible layer for *source code* and *scripts*, it does not provide an **[ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) [loader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loader_%28computing%29)** nor does it implement the Linux [**ABI**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface), therefore it cannot run Linux binaries.

Answer (score 1):

no (because cygwin binaries are WINDOWS binaries).

but you can setup a virtual machine (with virtualbox.org), install linux in it and then run the fortran compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Better (easier to install and configure) than cygwin is http://andlinux.org and you can get intel fortran compilers through andlinux.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, GCC (including GFortran) supports Cygwin, see:  http://gcc.gnu.org/install/specific.html#x-x-cygwin